# Would having a './' in a URL cause any trouble with search engines?

Tags: seo, url, search-engines

For code simplicity, some of my URLs in my website might contain a `./`

For example:

> www.example.com/./something

The `./` is automatically stripped-out by the browser, and the resulting URL is:

> www.example.com/something

My question is: could such URLs cause any trouble? Will search engines be able to correctly resolve these URLs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No they will not cause any issues (nor do you need to do any kind of redirect). RFC 3986 (the official URI spec) specifies a "Reference Resolution" section which states any path segments (between slashes) containing only dots [should be removed](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2.4). Single dots are removed entirely while double dots essentially remove the previous directory from the URL.

Also note that no file system in popular use (Windows/Mac/Linux) allows a filename composed of just dots so a URL containing `/./` doesn't really make sense.

In short, when any user agent (browser or search engine) sees a URL containing a single dot it won't ever request that URL, it will request the "proper" one.

Comment: +1 for the 'nor do you need to do any kind of redirect'.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you will have a rewrite rule that will strip it out by doing a permanent redirect (301). That way, These URLs will never be resolved, only the correct one.